# Why same paths of xgboost tree give 2 different predictions?

Tags: machine-learning, scikit-learn, xgboost

I'm trying to investigate the `xgboost` prediction.

It seems that 2 inputs with same 2 paths gives 2 different predictions.

I'm running on the following dateset:

```py
f1,f2,f3,f4,f5,f6,f7,f8,y
6,148,72,35,0,33.6,0.627,50,1
1,85,66,29,0,26.6,0.351,31,0
8,183,64,0,0,23.3,0.672,32,1
1,89,66,23,94,28.1,0.167,21,0
0,137,40,35,168,43.1,2.288,33,1
5,116,74,0,0,25.6,0.201,30,0
3,78,50,32,88,31.0,0.248,26,1
10,115,0,0,0,35.3,0.134,29,0
2,197,70,45,543,30.5,0.158,53,1
8,125,96,0,0,0.0,0.232,54,1
4,110,92,0,0,37.6,0.191,30,0
10,168,74,0,0,38.0,0.537,34,1
10,139,80,0,0,27.1,1.441,57,0
1,189,60,23,846,30.1,0.398,59,1
5,166,72,19,175,25.8,0.587,51,1
7,100,0,0,0,30.0,0.484,32,1
0,118,84,47,230,45.8,0.551,31,1
7,107,74,0,0,29.6,0.254,31,1
1,103,30,38,83,43.3,0.183,33,0
1,115,70,30,96,34.6,0.529,32,1
3,126,88,41,235,39.3,0.704,27,0
8,99,84,0,0,35.4,0.388,50,0
7,196,90,0,0,39.8,0.451,41,1
9,119,80,35,0,29.0,0.263,29,1
11,143,94,33,146,36.6,0.254,51,1
10,125,70,26,115,31.1,0.205,41,1
7,147,76,0,0,39.4,0.257,43,1
1,97,66,15,140,23.2,0.487,22,0
13,145,82,19,110,22.2,0.245,57,0
5,117,92,0,0,34.1,0.337,38,0
5,109,75,26,0,36.0,0.546,60,0
3,158,76,36,245,31.6,0.851,28,1
3,88,58,11,54,24.8,0.267,22,0
6,92,92,0,0,19.9,0.188,28,0
10,122,78,31,0,27.6,0.512,45,0
4,103,60,33,192,24.0,0.966,33,0
11,138,76,0,0,33.2,0.420,35,0
9,102,76,37,0,32.9,0.665,46,1
2,90,68,42,0,38.2,0.503,27,1
```

prediction and tree creation code:

```py
df = pd.read_csv("input.csv")
x = df[['f1','f2','f3', 'f4', 'f5', 'f6','f7','f8']]
y = df[['y']]
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split( x, y, test_size = 0.33, random_state = 42)
model = XGBClassifier(n_jobs=-1)
model.fit(X_train, y_train)
res = model.predict(X_test)
print ("X_test (first 2 rows:")
print(X_test.head(2))
print("Predictions (first 2 rows:")
print(res[0:2])    
plot_tree(model)
plt.show()
```

Output:

```py
X_test (first 2 rows:
    f1   f2  f3  f4  f5    f6     f7  f8
33   6   92  92   0   0  19.9  0.188  28
36  11  138  76   0   0  33.2  0.420  35
Predictions (first 2 rows:
[0 1]
```

[image]

The same 2 inputs have `f2<146.5` and `f4=0` => get into same leaf (`-0.34`)
So why the prediction for those 2 are different ? (`0 and 1`) ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you have plotted in *not* the whole XGBoost model; it is only the first tree of it.

To see why this is so, check the [source code](https://github.com/dmlc/xgboost/blob/master/python-package/xgboost/plotting.py#L214) of `plot_tree`:

```py
def plot_tree(booster, fmap='', num_trees=0, rankdir=None, ax=None, **kwargs):
    """Plot specified tree.
```

and the [documentation](https://xgboost.readthedocs.io/en/latest/python/python_api.html#xgboost.plot_tree):

> `num_trees` (int, default 0) – Specify the ordinal number of target tree

from where it is apparent that, when you do not specify the `num_trees` argument, like here, it takes the default value of `0`, i.e. the first tree of the ensemble.

Using different values for `num_trees` you will get different trees, hence different decision paths for each sample.

You cannot plot all the trees of the boosting ensemble (and even if you could, it would not be of any practical use). `plot_tree` is just a utility function in order to be able to have a look at individual trees of the model. You can have a look at its use in [How to Visualize Gradient Boosting Decision Trees With XGBoost in Python](https://machinelearningmastery.com/visualize-gradient-boosting-decision-trees-xgboost-python/).

Comment: It might also be instructive to use the `n_tree_limit` (or the new `iteration_range`) parameter of `predict`, or perhaps `apply` instead of `predict`, to see that the first tree's prediction is what was expected.